# Загрузка js файлов после загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Есть не большая проблема,

Загрузка страниц на моем сайте происходит в 2 этапа, изначально загружается шапка и вставляется на страницу, затем тело страницы. Получание страницы происходит через `ajax`. Проблема заключается в том что необходимо подгружать js файлы после того как загрузится тело, однако есть вставить это `<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts/tagsinput.js"></script>` в файле где находится тело страницы, то после того как ajax получит страницу и вставит ее на сайт никаких подгрузок не происходит. Как можно было бы исправить это?

Comment: У вас подгружаемые js зависят от подгружаемого содержимого?

Comment: @br3t, да так как если подгружать js раньше чем загрузится тело, ничего работать не будет

Comment: Много ли этих подключаемых файлов? Можно подключить их все; при загрузке каждой порции контента ajaxoм в функции обратного вызова можно вызывать нужное кастомное событие, которое будет перехватываться нужным скриптом и соответствующим образом обрабатываться.  Пользовательские события можно обрабатывать с помощью делегирования.

Comment: @br3t, Проблема в том, что нужно подгружать относительно большие файлы, по этому таким образом вызывать не получится. И еще, ajax запрос у меня стандартный для всех страницы, по это как я уже сказал, данный способ не очень подходит.

Comment: Разобрался, нужно было подгружать через $('body').append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете же просто использовать `jquery` для подгрузки документов:
Логика следующая:
 - Вы загружаете страницу.
 - На неё загружаете `header`.
 - Загружаете тело страницы.
 - Отслеживаете загрузку страницы и добавляете в загруженный документ новый `html`, который содержит ссылки на скрипты.

Например первый файл `help48.html`:

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
    .main{
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: #003eff;
    }
</style>
<div class="main">
    <div class="add">
    </div></div>
<button id="but">Добавить файл</button>
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(window).on('load', function () { // При загрузке документа
        $('#but').on('click', function () { // Отслеживаем нажатие кнопки
            $('.add').load('help49.html'); // Подгружаем файл в поле с классом add
        })
    })
</script>
```

Второй файл, который подгружаем - `help49.html`:

```
<script src="help59.js"></script>
```

Третий файл сам `js` -  `help59.js`:

```
let z = document.getElementsByClassName('add')[0];
z.innerText = 'zzzzzzz';
```

Запускаем первый файл:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажимаем кнопку подгрузки другого документа(результат нажатия):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видим из результата - данные подгружаются корректно и сразу выполняются.